# A JVM gc log anaylize

Tags: jvm

JVM params:

```
-server -Xmx2g -Xms2g -Xmn256m -Xss256k -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:LargePageSizeInBytes=128m -XX:+UseFastAccessorMethods -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70 -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Xloggc:logs/gc.log -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
```

Java -version

```
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

GC log:

```
4728.367: [GC (Allocation Failure) 4728.367: [ParNew: 210107K->314K(235968K), 0.0041113 secs] 650117K->440325K(2070976K), 0.0042571 secs] [Times: user=0.03 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs]
4729.843: [GC (Allocation Failure) 4729.843: [ParNew: 210106K->4023K(235968K), 0.0061596 secs] 650117K->444034K(2070976K), 0.0063117 secs] [Times: user=0.04 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs]
4730.447: [GC (Allocation Failure) 4730.447: [ParNew: 212630K->2166K(235968K), 0.0202457 secs] 652642K->442177K(2070976K), 0.0203974 secs] [Times: user=0.22 sys=0.01, real=0.02 secs]
4731.010: [GC (Allocation Failure) 4731.010: [ParNew: 211598K->1463K(235968K), 0.0256586 secs] 651610K->441475K(2070976K), 0.0258524 secs] [Times: user=0.04 sys=0.01, real=0.02 secs]
4731.583: [GC (Allocation Failure) 4731.583: [ParNew: 211255K->528K(235968K), 0.0200805 secs] 651267K->440572K(2070976K), 0.0202633 secs] [Times: user=0.10 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs]
4732.153: [GC (Allocation Failure) 4732.153: [ParNew: 210320K->3971K(235968K), 0.0032271 secs] 650364K->444130K(2070976K), 0.0033627 secs] [Times: user=0.04 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs]
```

I use [GCViewer](https://github.com/chewiebug/GCViewer)! to analyze GC log.

part of the result showed as following:

```
Total heap(usage / alloc.max)  625.9M(30.9%)/2,022.4M
Tenured heap(usage / alloc.max)  415M(23.2%)/1,792M
Young heap(usage / alloc.max)    212.5(92.2%)/230.4M
```

Does memory leak? or how to optimize JVM parameters?

Comment: The options `-Xmn256m -Xss256k -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:LargePageSizeInBytes=128m -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70` suggest that you *did* already optimize the JVM. If these options were not the result of optimization, you should remove all of them, to gather statistics which are not the result of your own explicit options. Then, *if* there are actual performance problems, add those options which actually improve the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Is difficult, if not impossible to tell whether there is a memory leak from this logs.

`[GC (Allocation Failure)` means that memory couldn't be allocated in the young generation chunk, this *Allocation Failure* triggers the garbage collector (GC).

It can be seen that the allocated heap for the young generation is running out of space at 92%, the program requires more *new* memory, but there is not enough new memory, so the GC has to do a clean up to free some memory.

Since there is still plenty of free space in the other heap areas, I would rather look into what is causing the program to create new objects so fast, instead of tweaking the JVM parameters.

Comment: Thanks! it has several kafka consumer instances and there are a large number of temporary variables in the process of processing the business logic.